# JSON from array not being parsed correctly

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm sending my mysql result to an associative array and then encoding with JSON

```
$showDisplayResult = $mysqlConn->query($getDisplayPage);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($showDisplayResult))
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
$showDisplays = json_encode($rows);
```

ANd in my main page I'm using javascript to grab this, parse it and append the correct variables into my URL. The functionality seems to work but it only shows undefined as the variables in the URL.

Here's the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

let obj = <?php echo $showDisplays; ?>;

//obj = JSON.parse(obj);

let params = new URL(document.location).searchParams;
params.set("pageID", obj.pageID);
params.set("display", obj.display_id);
let url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
let nextURL = url + "?" + params.toString();
window.setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = nextURL;
}, obj.duration * 1000);

console.log(obj);
</script>
```

So my URL is now showDisplay.php?display=undefined&pageID=undefined

How can I get this to parse the JSON correctly?

UPDATE:

If I echo $showDisplays, this is the JSON that prints:

```
[{"pageID":"104","page_type_id":"1","display_id":"3","slide_order":null,"duration":"56","active":"1","background_img":null,"panel_id":"96","panel_type_id":"1","page_id":"104","cont_id":"148","contID":"148","content":"\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nThis is full content<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"},{"pageID":"116","page_type_id":"1","display_id":"3","slide_order":null,"duration":"54","active":"1","background_img":"images\/BG_spring.svg","panel_id":"113","panel_type_id":"1","page_id":"116","cont_id":"165","contID":"165","content":"\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nThis background should be green<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"}]
```

So on page load i want the url to have `display=3&pageID=104` then after 56 seconds (its duration) it should refresh and th URL should be `display=3&pageID=116` for 54 seconds, and then keep the loop

Comment: Why is `JSON.parse(obj)` commented out?

Comment: please add `obj`.

Comment: @MarkMeyer when I comment this line out, the functionality at least is there but when it's left in at no longer appends anything to the URL and the console says it can't read property 'pageID' of null

Comment: Why are you looping and adding a row to an array if you are only expecting one `pageID` etc???

Comment: @abracadaver I'm expecting more than one, with this particular displayID I have 3 pages assigned to it. I'm trying to build a JSON of all pages assiged to the display so that it can loop trhough and append each one to the URL on refresh. It's just cycling slides after a duration basically

Comment: This `$showDisplays = json_encode($rows);` encodes it and saves it in a variable. It does not return it to the javascript

Comment: @AbraCadaver but I'm sure there's a better way of doing it. I'm passing a variable in the url to this page for display, using that in my query to get all pages assigned to that display, and then load the pages information into JSON so that I can cycle the URLs as slides

Comment: Well, you are not looping in the JS so which `obj.pageID` are you expecting???

Comment: @AbraCadaver honestly because I'm just a PHP guy but the php site I built needs to display these static pages on displays and loop through slides, which is where the JS comes in and I'm super green in this arena

Comment: @AbraCadaver I'm sure it should be simple but I just don't really know the approach to take from here

Comment: @AbraCadaver do you have any suggestion on how I should change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read the code correctly, `$showDisplays` is an array of row objects, not a single row object. The JavaScript, however, tries to access properties of a row object as if they were on their containing array, `obj`.

If you want to access properties of the first row object in the array, you can do this with:

```
params.set("pageID", obj[0].pageID);
params.set("display", obj[0].display_id);
```

The next row object would be at the next index, `obj[1]`. So, in order to get all of the row objects in sequence, you would loop over them.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: This is making a bit more sense, but can you view my update where I added the JSON currently being printed and my example in the case of that object

Comment: @TomN. I cleaned up my answer. For a better answer regarding what you are trying to do, I suggest you ask a new question, as it is beyond the scope of this one.

Comment: Thank you, I think that answers my question. Basically if I don't know how many rows there may be ill just make it a JS loop

Comment: @TomN. Exactly!